# Shortening turn off time of a PSU output

Tags: power-supply

I have 15W 5V power supply ([Meanwell HDR-15-5](https://docs.rs-online.com/6188/0900766b815d9411.pdf)) which I use it to power an STM32 Nucleo board through its E5V and GND pins. The Nucleo controls an OLED and a current sensor ect.

But I noticed the when the mains of the power supply is turned of the PSU turns off very slowly (probably due to its output caps). This becomes problematic when the mains is turned of and on very quickly before the OLED turns off completely.

So what I need is, I want the power supply's 5V DC output to turn off faster when the mains input is turned off. First thing came to my mind is to add a resistor between PSU output terminals.
If I use quarter watt resistor P = V<sup>2</sup>/R so Rmin = 5<sup>2</sup>/0.25 = 100 ohms. So I think this is theoretical limit.

Is that's the best way is there a way to size such a resistor(quarter watt resistor) looking at the PSU datasheet?

Comment: Do you know how much current your dircuit draws?

Comment: But what is the problem if the power is turned off and on too quickly? Does the MCU continue running but OLED resets, or what? Is how is the OLED powered? Because you likely have an X-Y problem. Problem is with the display and you try to solve it with adding a resistor and are asking how to solve the resistor problem, but you should be asking how to solve the LCD problem.

Comment: @Justme  As far as I observe what happens is this: I turn off the mains, the MCU board(Nucleo) turns off first(at least its LED indicates that), the OLED is still in process of turning off(its becoming dimmer) and if at that moment I turn on the mains both the OLED and  and the I2C current sensor not working. (Both OLED and I2C is powered from Nucleo pins). Nucleo is powered from its E5V pin by the PSU)

Comment: I suppose the OLED or current sensor chips have no reset pin? Or you can't control their power from the MCU? What does "not working" even mean? What do the I2C pins do in that situation, what error you get if you try to communicate with the I2C devices?

Comment: Adding a resistor will just load your circuit at all times -> waste of power as heat. Do you need a DIN rail psu ? You may not run into this long hold-up time issue with a small power brick 5V-1A if that's within your specs.

Comment: @Rahmany Yes has to be DIN rail.

Comment: @Justme OLED is 4-pin type with no reset. I had issues with it it was randomly turning on but fixed it in a way and had no problem with bench PSU. This new issue is caused by PSU turning off too slow. I will open a question and share the initial code and link it here in a few minutes.

Comment: @Justme Here is new question more details with the history: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/636606/oled-start-up-issue-with-stm32-board

Comment: Why not use a mains powered relay to open circuit the output to your circuit? Could be an opto-isolator based version with a power MOSFET on the DC side also.

Comment: @Andyaka Restricted with the current equipment. I cant.:((

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relay-based solution.

[image]

Comment: This solution was suggested and debunked in the comments already.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.